# connect() giving ENOENT - what could be the cause?

Tags: c, sockets, errno

I am testing a project that uses UNIX sockets and I can't seem to connect the clients to the listening server. Errno returns `ENOENT`. I've checked if it may be something else, it's not. Checked online, can't find when connect returns `ENOENT`.

I've tried creating a minimal reproducible example but it gives no errors, I have no clue of what I may be doing wrong in the original project.

So, when does connect return `ENOENT/errno 2`?

Comment: You're giving the wrong path to the socket. Make sure it's an absolute path, not relative, since a relative path would depend on the directory the client user is in.

Comment: [POSIX connect](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/connect.html): `[ENOENT] A component of the pathname does not name an existing file or the pathname is an empty string.`

Comment: @Barmar I think that's it because my program changes the current directory! Didn't think about using the absolute path, thanks!

Comment: Make sure you read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).  The process involves taking a copy of the code with the problem and then slowly removing extraneous material, checking frequently (and checking into your VCS — version control system — frequently too; you are using a VCS, aren't you?).  If a change prevents the problem reproducing, you need to revert and try again.